# Chrome scrollbar is see through

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm doing some web development and for some reason on some of the pages the scrollbar on the right side of the window is transparent or white when using Chrome.  I've looked through my css and I don't see any scrollbar styling set.  The scrollbars look normal in firefox.

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates this problem?  Otherwise, your question is just a guessing game.

Comment: I'm not sure what to post, other than maybe all my css...  I'm really not sure what's going on.  I've tried googling a solution, but haven't come up with anything useful.  I haven't seen anything useful relating to this type of a problem on SO either.  I'm not sure what I'd be looking for exactly.  I'm a summer intern taking over some development for someone else (and I'm by myself here).

Comment: Did you try the Developer Tools (F12) to see the live CSS?  Look for anything with the `overflow` property set to `hidden`.  Somewhere, something is getting clipped.  This could be done through CSS or perhaps JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If it's because the page is so short that no scroll bar is required, but you still want it to show up, you can set the `overflow-y` CSS property to `scroll` on the `html` element of the page. For example:

```
html {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: so, it happens when scrolling is indeed needed